# Zend optional route segment and parameter

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm trying to create a route in Zend 1.12 with a optional segment, but i don't know and i can't find a way to do it.

The situation is, i have the route:

```
$routes['news'] = array(
    'route'    => '/news/page/:page',
    'defaults' => array(
        'module'     => 'default',
        'controller' => 'news',
        'action'     => 'index',
        'page'       => 1,
    ),
    'reqs' => array(
        'page' => '([2-9][0-9]*)',
    ),
);
```

But i need the segment of the route `/page/:page` does not appear when the page is 1

Example:

Page = 1 -> `/news`

Page = 2 -> `/news/page/2`

Any ideas how can i do it?